# oracle indexes to be executed in parallel

Tags: oracle10g

In oracle, Can i run index rebuild in parallel , all indexes belonging to same table.

We have a dyanmic sql procedure for rebuilding indexes, so can call that procedure in parallel for 3 indexes belonging to same table.

Regards,
Shi

Answer (score 0):

I think it should cause no problems, you might want to check if the columns of the index overlap or not.

refer this for more info:

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2913600659112

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must create indexes on existing table with data with PARALLEL ON and you can recreate them afterwards with NO-PARALLEL to avoid further processing degradation while insert data.